# sql garbage collection vs cleaning up queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, collections, duplicates, garbage

so, I have made a php script that produces the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM icecream WHERE 
flavor = 'vanilla' AND color = 'purple' AND (quality = 'aaa') 
OR flavor = 'marzipan' AND color = 'purple' AND (quality = 'aaa')  
OR flavor = 'vanilla' AND color = 'purple' AND (quality = 'aaa')
```

The last and first bit of the query are identical.

That looks wrong to me, and obviously I'd much rather like to run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM icecream WHERE 
flavor = 'vanilla' AND color = 'purple' AND (quality = 'aaa') 
OR flavor = 'marzipan' AND color = 'purple' AND (quality = 'aaa')
```

omitting the last row.

Which looks fine in this example, but let's say that
 1. There might be 23 "OR flavor..." parts instead
 2. 100 different flavors
 3. 50 different colors
 4. 20 different quality ratings.

Suddenly it becomes a lot more complex to create a nice looking SQL query without duplicate requests for the same data.

The current SQL query works. But should I clean up the query to eliminate the duplication, or should I leave it to the SQL engine to do it for me?

I mean, I can do it...but is it worth it? On one hand I want to pass clean SQL queries, but on the other it seems like these kinds of things is what an SQL engine really is designed to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please note: just because `OR` is on a new line, it doesn't make that segment of your SQL as a separate condition. In the absence of the brackets `( <condition> AND/OR <condition>)`, the evaluation would be sequential. As an aside, your might want to take a look at [`IN` operator](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)

Comment: For sure, i just did that for readability so people could easily see the duplication.

I have thought about using the IN operator and an ID using all three different parts.

xxxyyzz

where x = flavor, y = color, z = quality.

That could be an easy solution, but there is a scalability issue. If the number of one of these values increases to include an extra digit then the entire system needs to be reworked.

Comment: And yes, I want it to be sequential. The ID of quality = 'aaa' and quality = 'aa' would be different so it's all proper.

Also, since there could be 100 flavors * 50 colors = 5000 different ID's by not using the parenthesis on aaa and aa for quality that would balloon up to 10000 different ID's, when all I want is the ID's for 2 ice creams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer your question by reading the query plan created by the MySQL optimizer, using `EXPLAIN [EXTENDED] SELECT ...`.  If the plans are the same, then the server not only considers your queries logically equivalent, but that it has reduced them down to the same query internally.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Your preference should be for the generated queries to be logically optimal, not doing things that can reduce the options available to the optimizer (by doing undesirable things like using column names as function arguments in `WHERE`, and be eyeball debuggable.  There's no need for cleverness.

```
(a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c = 5) OR
(a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c = 27)
```

...is entirely equivalent to...

```
(a = 1 AND b = 1) AND (c = 5 OR c = 27)
```

....or...

```
(a = 1 AND b = 1 AND c IN (5,27))
```

...and the optimizer will easily understand these conditions regardless of how they are expressed in the query. The resulting plan should be identical, so there's no need to prefer one over the others when generating dynamic queries.  (Older versions of MySQL might not necessarily have handled the last one as well as they might have handled the first two but this should not be an issue, now.)

Importantly, `WHERE` of course, being a logical expression, has deterministic evaluation precedence from a logical perspective, but that is not the same as ordering of evaluation against each row... there is, theoretically, no order in which the evaluation of the conditions of the final expression are ordered -- but the optimizer is free to *actually* evaluate the conditions in any order that seems right and optimal, regardless of how they are expressed.

Based on index lookups, here, it might choose to find all `b = 1` rows, then find `c = 5 OR c = 27` within that set, and finally scan the resulting rows for the `a = 1` condition.  Such might be the case if you had a single index on columns `(b,c)`.  There is no shortcutting in the procedural sense -- `WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1` is logically identical to `WHERE b = 1 AND a = 1`.

Note that you should use more parentheses in the example queries so that the grouping of the AND/OR precedence is unambiguous.  The server will get it right, of course, but the eyeballs are more easily deceived, and parentheses that make things unambiguous to the eyeballs will do no disservice to the MySQL optimizer, which seems to love them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The questions I see are:

1) Will the SQL engine remove the duplication?

> these kinds of things is what an SQL engine really is designed to do

2) How can I pass clean queries without undue effort?

> I want to pass clean SQL queries

---

**SQL is declarative language.**

A [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) means that you tell it what to do, it determines how to do it.

In this case, the mysql engine will take your query and determine how to retrieve your data. The duplication in your query should be removed by the query parser as part of this process. (It is possible that the parser will not remove them, this would be dependent on the complexity of the query and the optimizations in place). The downside to this, is a slightly longer parse, though I do not expect the delay to be noticeable, especially in a complicated query with many where clauses.

---

**It seems that your php script is focusing on a low level of abstraction.**

My best guess is that your script takes some data and converts it into a string, it then repeats with conversion, with the next piece of the data.

The downside to this method is modifying, or tweaking, the result object. The converter does not know what happened in a prior step and can not easily detect and remove the duplicate lines. What you need to do is to have some sort of object that can help take some rules and build a sql query out of it. (One such tool is [Zend Db](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/db-adapter/)).

---

Finally, I would just want to note, that the query you are trying to make seems needlessly complex.

> 23 "OR flavor..." parts

Or course, while it is possible that you will need to make such a complex query, a complex query has more areas where performance can suffer. It might be more prudent to examine what you are trying to accomplish and determine if there is a more direct method to get it. As it stands I do not have enough information to see if there is another way.